# Passing variables between subs inside class

Tags: arrays, vb.net, sqlite, variables

This may have been asked and answered several times, but I have been unable to find the answer.

In `CbProdukt1_SelectedIndexChanged()`, I need the associated value from an array from another sub:

```
Private Sub CbProdukt1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles CbProdukt1.SelectedIndexChanged

    With Me.LblEnhed1
         .Text = Enhed(CbProdukt1.SelectedIndex)
         .Location = New Point(230, 150)
    End With
    Me.Controls.Add(LblEnhed1)

End Sub
```

This would be easy enough if `Enhed()` had been public. But it is not as it is dimensioned and retrieved from Sqlite in another sub:

```
Dim count As Integer
sql = "SELECT COUNT(varenr) AS varenrcount FROM '" & Varedatabase & "'"
cmd = New SQLiteCommand(sql, conn)
count = cmd.ExecuteScalar

sql = "SELECT * FROM '" & Varedatabase & "'"
cmd = New SQLiteCommand(sql, conn)
reader = cmd.ExecuteReader

Dim a = 0
Dim Varenr(count + 5) As String
Dim Varenavn(count + 5) As String
Dim Enhed(count + 5) As String

While (reader.Read())
    Varenr(a) = reader("varenr")
    Varenavn(a) = reader("Varenavn")
    Enhed(a) = reader("Enhed")
    CbProdukt1.Items.Add(varenavn(a))
    a += 1
End While
```

Public declarations are only allowed prior to subs at the top of the class.

So how do I get the Enhed(a) from sub to sub?

Comment: What language is this in, Visual Basic? Might be helpful to add the language to tags.

Comment: Can you show more of your code so that we can help you out?

Comment: I do apologise. It seems that my problem has been a lack of high level understanding of certain issues of Vb.net. I have finally figured out how to do this. It is quite simple of course.
I declare a public var in module1.vb (I thought I could do it in the main menu form!) and check the number of database records in the sub calling this form instead of doing it after I loaded the form.
Thanks :)